# How can get data with multilanguage in one table (codeingiter , Mysql , Php )

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How are you ?

My site have a multi languages (English , French , Arabic ,  .. etc) , I have in my backend tables to showing the content ( posts ) ..

I want to showing in this table ( title , content , support languages )

look at database structure

http://saudi-hotels.info/tables.jpg

[image]

I want to showing data like this table

http://saudi-hotels.info/table_information.jpg

[image]

I tried to get a good query , but I can't look at my query:

```
$this->db->from('localization_posts PL');
        $this->db->join('posts PO' , 'PO.id_post = PL.id_post');
        $this->db->join('langauges LN', 'LN.id_language = PL.id_langauge');
        $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: Your `localization_posts`'s `id_language` should be `INT`.

Comment: Thanks , I know id should be INT , but this is not my question ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm not wrong you want given kind of query.

Try this.

```
SELECT lp.title_post, lp.content_post, p.views_post, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(l.id_language) AS l.support_language 
FROM localization_posts lp
INNER JOIN posts p ON lp.id_post = p.id_post
LEFT JOIN languages l ON lp.id_language = l.id_language;
```

Hope will help.

Comment: amazing , This is what I want , Thank you very much , ^_^